# How to ingest log from remote solaris sparc 10 host to logstash on centos 7?

Tags: logstash, solaris, sparc

Logstash is install on Centos 7. Log file is on Solaris Sparc 10 remote host. What is the best way to ingest live log file from Sparc to Logstash?

Comment: "best" is subjective.  In the elastic stack, you'd use filebeats to ship the file to logstash.

Comment: Logs are on Solaris Sparc and I don't believe Filebeat is available.